# kernel panic after shrinking with PiShrink-macOS

Tags: boot, sd-card

I tried to use multiple times self compiled PiShrink-macOS from this repository https://github.com/lisanet/PiShrink-macOS on my Mac OSx Big Sur 11.4, but when triyng to boot shrinked image, it always ends with kernel panic even it looks that process went well.

```
Copying 2021_rpi_zizkovpi.img to 2021_rpi_shrinked.img...
e2fsck 1.44.0 (7-Mar-2018)
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Pass 2: Checking directory structure
Pass 3: Checking directory connectivity
Pass 4: Checking reference counts
Pass 5: Checking group summary information
/dev/disk2s2: 312456/956592 files (0.9% non-contiguous), 2647926/3822720 blocks
resize2fs 1.44.0 (7-Mar-2018)
resize2fs 1.44.0 (7-Mar-2018)
Resizing the filesystem on /dev/disk2s2 to 2980438 (4k) blocks.
Begin pass 2 (max = 603103)
Relocating blocks             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Begin pass 3 (max = 117)
Scanning inode table          XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Begin pass 4 (max = 41487)
Updating inode references     XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
The filesystem on /dev/disk2s2 is now 2980438 (4k) blocks long.

"disk2" ejected.
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
Enter 'help' for information
fdisk: 1>          Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2: 83   33  69  37 - 1023 254  63 [    534528 -   30581760] Linux files*
Partition id ('0' to disable)  [0 - FF]: [83] (? for help) Do you wish to edit in CHS mode? [n] Partition offset [0 - 31116288]: [532480] Partition size [1 - 30583808]: [30583808] fdisk:*1> Writing MBR at offset 0.
fdisk: 1> Shrunk 2021_rpi_zizkovpi_shrinked.img from 15G to 12G
```

anyone would know what could be be cause and how to fix it?

[image: screen shot of kernel panic]

Comment: A kernel panic suggests that your kernel seems to boot. Does it leave any logging on the SD card (in `/var/log`) that shows at what point it panics?

Comment: i was able to get screenshot

Comment: "Unable to mount root"; that means that the boot process is not able to access the rootfs. If you have a linux system, you could try an `fsck` on the rootfs.

Comment: It is unclear what this program actually does but as macOS has no support for ext4 it is unlikely to succeed.

Comment: the quickest solution for me was to install vmware and run virtualised linux with pishring from this `https://github.com/Drewsif/PiShrink` repository